# How did 'decree' evolve from 'to separate'?

Tags: etymology

What's an intuitive derivation or rationale to help remember the definition?   I purpose to burrow below definitions, which I already understand so ask NOT about. I heed the Etymological Fallacy.

> [**decree**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/decree) = {noun} 1. An official `order` that has the force of law:
>
> = {verb} [with object] Order (something) by decree
>
> [Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=decree&searchmode=none): early 14c., from Old French *decre*, variant of *decret* (12c., Modern French décret), from Latin *decretum*, neuter of *decretus*, past participle of *decernere* "to decree, decide, pronounce a decision," from ***de-*** (see [de-](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=de-&allowed_in_frame=0)) + ***cernere*** **"to separate"** (see [crisis](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=crisis&allowed_in_frame=0)).

My especial concern:
How does **"to separate"**    effect/imply/induce the definitions, given that **"to separate"** (the original) and `order` (modern) fail to relate to each other?

Footnote: Unhelpfully and oddly, OED's entries for [the verb](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/48430?rskey=HbSYvU&result=2&isAdvanced=false) and [the noun](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/48429) are both too terse.

Comment: Mnemonic: Solomon preparing to chop the baby in half. _Decretum_ was a well established legal term in Roman times. [The _False Deccretals_](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-Isidorian_Decretals) as a term goes back over a millennium. It means to make a decision, i.e, to decide between two petitioners.  Separation is the key.

Comment: @JohnLawler that's fascinating. Do you have a reference for it? My guess would simply be that the first "decrees" in history all dealt with enforcing some kind of separation of things, be it land, food, time allocation, et al

Comment: That's what they always do. That's why Justice holds a balance scale.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As your research demonstrates, *decree* is related to *[crisis](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=crisis&allowed_in_frame=0)*:

> *crisis:*
>
> early 15c., from Latinized form of Greek *krisis* "turning point in a
>   disease" (used as such by Hippocrates and Galen), literally "*judgment*,
>   result of a trial, *selection*,"
>
> from *krinein* "to *separate*, *decide*, *judge*,"
>
> from PIE root * *krei*- "*to sieve*, *discriminate*, *distinguish*"
>
> (cognates: Greek *krinesthai* "to *explain*;" Old English *hriddel* "*sieve*;"
>   Latin *cribrum* "*sieve*," *crimen* "*judgment*, *crime*," *cernere* (past
>   participle *cretus*) "to *sift*, *separate*;" Old Irish *criathar*, Old Welsh
>   *cruitr* "*sieve*;" Middle Irish *crich* "*border*, *boundary*").
>
> Transferred non-medical sense is 1620s in English. A German term for
>   "mid-life crisis" is Torschlusspanik, literally "shut-door-panic,"
>   fear of being on the wrong side of a closing gate.

Intuitively, when conflicting arguments were presented to a judge, he did what the PIE root and all of the cognates imply: he **sifted** through all of the evidence, **discriminated** between conflicting opinions, **distinguished** truth from fiction, **decided** the case, then **explained** his decision, which become the new **boundary** between the contestants. Our explicit *discernment* of that process may be clouded, but linguistically, the *decree* is the outcome of the *crisis*.

> *de-* (concerning, down to the bottom, completely) + *cernere* (sifting,
>   separation) yields:
>
> ***concerning the judgement*** or ***complete judgement***

Answer (score 0):

It might be helpful to compare *discern*, which has a similar etymology.  *Discern* means to distinguish the right choice from the wrong one.

A *decree* distinguishes what may be done from what may not be done.